When using docker-compose why are my files mounting like folders?
I tried the following...
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra:/cassandra
      - ./cassandra/init-cassandra.cql:/etc/cassandra/init-cassandra.cql

where
$ ls -al cassandra/init.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 228 Aug 29 16:36 'cassandra/init.sh'

But when I exec into the image I see the files but they are directories
root@e896458f2fd0:/# ls -l cassandra
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 cassandra root 40 Aug 29 20:10 init-cassandra.cql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root 40 Aug 29 20:38 init.sh
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root 60 Aug 29 20:38 out

But it shouldn't be a directory
full Yaml
  init:
    image: containerregistry-na.jpmchase.net/container-external/docker.io/cassandra:4.0.0
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra:/cassandra
      - ./cassandra/init-cassandra.cql:/etc/cassandra/init-cassandra.cql


It looks like your file is called cassandra/init.sh with a slash in the filename, rather than a file called init.sh in a cassandra directory. So compose can't find ./cassandra/init.sh because it expects a directory with a file in it. And when it can't find the host element you map, it creates a directory and maps that. I expect that you now have a cassandra directory with a init.sh in it which is also a directory. And that's what has been mapped.

This was due some permissioning issues with the virtual file system we were using. I had to make sure the folder I was using was in my User folder to avoid this.
